# Text Field name programatically in swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode

I've below form:-
[image]

I've created this form programatically.
The code for this is below:-

```
   let textFiled = UITextField(frame:CGRectMake(87.0, y, 100.0, 20.0))
    textFiled.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.Line
     textFiled.font =  UIFont.systemFontOfSize(8)
```

Now if I set tag for these text field then it'll store **Int** value. Which is very tough for me to manipulate this form.

I want to **set name like IBOutlet for each text field**. So that I can easily handle this form.

Is it possible to do it in Swift 4...

I want Your opinion please....

Comment: `zipTextField.placeholder = "Hardcoded: Zip" // TODO: localize me`  

and for text:
`zipTextField.text = "12345"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to tag, we have

> accessibilityIdentifier

in which you can add String values
you can just say

```
textFiled.accessibilityIdentifier = "name"
```

and get value using the below:-

```
textFiled.accessibilityIdentifier
```

UPDATE:

I suggest we never use the `accessibilityIdentifier` as it's for testing, for your case you should subclass UITextField and add a custom property to identify the text field

Comment: yes, I'm getting proper identifier. Working fine. is it possible to get value by this accessibilityIdentifier...

Comment: @ripa no, that's not possible i think

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191456/discussion-between-ripa-and-krishnapal-gohil).